# Can't run scrapy command to run spider on heroku cloud

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the scrapy command to run when I type `heroku run scrapy crawl amazing` on the top level of the project.
The spider is in my directory `webscraper_git/web scraper/spiders`, even after I run the command under the `webscraper_git/web scraper/spiders`, where the spider(amazing) is, it doesn't work.
I just get bash: `scrapy: command not found`

I have Scrapy in my requirements.txt file as well as a scrapy.cfg file. I can run scrapy locally just fine.

Comment: my requirements.txt have: 
dj-database-url==0.4.1, Django==1.9.7, gunicorn==19.6.0, psycopg2==2.6.1, whitenoise==2.0.6, cffi==1.1.0, python-2.7.13

my procfile has web: scrapy crawl amazing 
my scrapy.cfg:
[settings]
default = webscraper.settings

[deploy]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = webscraper

Comment: I definitely can't see Scrapy in your requirements.txt, is it complete? Try to run `python -m scrapy.cmdline crawl amazing` instead of `scrapy crawl amazing`

Comment: @mizhgun I added the scrapy version to it and used that command it throws a "raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)" which is expected because I don't want to scrape a site right when I run it rather I want it hosted on a server and then I make a request to it dynamically with whatever website I want it to scrape for me